# Pyrex - 'PyFrameObject' is not declared

Tags: python, pyrex

I'm trying to migrate one secret c-based library from CentOS 6.5/Python 2.6 to CentOS 7.4/Python 2.7. This library has python interface which based on Pyrex.

The problem is, when I execute 'pyrex secret_lib.pyx' (first line of this file - include "python.pxi")I get these errors:

```
python.pxi:165:8 'PyFrameObject' is not declared
python.pxi:165:8 'PyFrameObject' is not a type identifier
```

Content of python.pxi:

```
 17 cdef extern from "Python.h":
...
164     ctypedef struct PyFrameObject:                                              
165         PyFrameObject *f_back                                                   
166         PyCodeObject  *f_code                                                   
167         PyObject *f_builtins                                                    
168         PyObject *f_globals                                                     
169         PyObject *f_locals                                                      
170         PyObject *f_trace                                                       
171         PyObject *f_exc_type                                                    
172         PyObject *f_exc_value                                                   
173         PyObject *f_exc_traceback                                               
174         int f_lasti                                                             
175         int f_lineno                                                            
176         int f_restricted                                                        
177         int f_iblock                                                            
178         int f_nlocals                                                           
179         int f_ncells                                                            
180         int f_nfreevars                                                         
181         int f_stacksize
```

So, here is this line - "165  PyFrameObject *f_back" and struct with the same name. Looks like linked list in c, thus why it's not defined? Or in Pyrex it means like extending predefined structure "PyFrameObject" - in this case it may cause error. But why?

I even tried to modify line 17 (3 different variants):

```
1) cdef extern from "Python.h, frameobject.h":
2) cdef extern from "frameobject.h":
3) cdef extern from *:
```

, but it didn't help.
In this file - "/usr/include/python2.7/frameobject.h" we can find this "PyFrameObject", so, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you certain that Pyrex has been used previously instead of Cython? The file extension is the same, `.pyx`.

Comment: Yes, because I have Makefile and there "pyrexc" is used to compile

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a "forward declaration" problem to me.

(I believe) When line 165 is being executed - `PyFrameObject` is not defined yet (it will be after line 181 - but not yet).

To resolve this try to tell the compiler that it will be defined by creating a forward declaration.

Searching the internet for that will likely help, e.g. https://www.mail-archive.com/cython-dev@codespeak.net/msg03160.html